# Sharepoint Custom Claims provider and Sharepoint profile “claim” data mapping

Tags: sharepoint-2010, provider, claims-based-identity

I have an custom claims provider that uses a IP-STS on Sharepoint 2010.
I want that a particular claim that comes from the IP-STS to map the Sharepoint user profile. 
i.e: 
Map the http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress claim to the "work email" field on the sharepoint's user profile

I want to do this automatically on the first time the user logs in, without any additional steps.

How can we accomplish that?
Just for your information, I've been researching pretty hard about it:

Even if I map it when I install the claims provider, this way:

```
$map = New-SPClaimTypeMapping "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "Email" -SameAsIncoming
```

I can't see the right info on the Sharepoint user profile.

Any help?

Thanks in advance